# Unnecessary Network Commands

Tags: network-programming, google-compute-engine, centos7

I'm running a virtual machine on GCE and Centos 7. I've configured the machine with two network interfaces. When doing so, the user is required to enter the following commands to configure eth1 (every interface except eth0 requires this approach). On my machine, eth1's gateway is 10.140.0.1.

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 10.140.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 10.140.0.2 mtu 1430
sudo echo "1 rt1" | sudo tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables # (sudo su - first if permission denied)
sudo ip route add 10.140.0.1 src 10.140.0.2 dev eth1
sudo ip route add default via 10.140.0.1 dev eth1 table rt1
sudo ip rule add from 10.140.0.2/20 table rt1
sudo ip rule add to 10.140.0.2/20 table rt1
```

I have used the above with success, but the configuration is not persistent. I know it's possible to do so, but I first need to fully understand what the above is actually doing (breaking my problem into smaller parts).

`sudo ifconfig eth1 10.140.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 10.140.0.2 mtu 1430`

This command seems to be telling eth1 at 10.140.0.2 to broadcast on the same internal IP. It's also setting MTU to 1430, which is strange because the other interfaces are set to 1460. Is this command really needed?

```
sudo echo "1 rt1" | sudo tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables # (sudo su - first if permission denied)
```

From what I read, this command is appending "1 rt1" to the file rt_tables. If this is run once, does it need to be run each time the network comes up? Seems like it only needs to be run once.

```
sudo ip route add 10.140.0.1 src 10.140.0.2 dev eth1
sudo ip route add default via 10.140.0.1 dev eth1 table rt1
sudo ip rule add from 10.140.0.2/20 table rt1
sudo ip rule add to 10.140.0.2/20 table rt1
```

I know these commands add non-persistent rules and routes to the network configuration. Once I know the answers to the above, I will come back to the approach of making this persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your question on [Google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/t86EmHt13DI), as I had mentioned in the post:

[IP routes](http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-tables.html) and [IP rules](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-rule.html) needs to be persistent routes to avoid the routes being lost after VM reboot or network services restart. Depending upon the operating system configuration files required to make the routes persistent can be different. Here is a [stackexchange thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354854/how-do-i-create-centos-7-persistent-policy-based-routing-rules) for CentOS 7, mentioning files: "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ethX" and "/etc/sysconfig/network/scripts/rule-ethX" to keep the IP route and rule peristent. Here is the [CentOS documentation](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html) for the persistent static routes.

Comment: Hey Navi - I've looked through those materials and have posted a follow up thread here after hitting a roadblock: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340700/instruction-ignored-in-etc-sysconfig-network-scripts-route-eth1-on-centos-7